# COUNTIF in Microsoft list

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, countif

I want to make an asset manager in Microsoft List via Sharepoint. The list should define a serial number to every item like this:

[image]

The challenge is that a running number should be the last charachter of serial number which counts the items in the same category/subcategory.

In Excel with CountIf function it is easy to do. But in MS Lists or with Power Automate I did not find the solution.

Do You have any idea?

Thank You

I need a category dependent running number when I define a new item in list.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using Office Scripts through PowerAutomate ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

... from here, you can write a script that performs the `COUNTIF` against the relevant dataset.

**Note:** *My answer assumes that you have the correct licence to do so.*